# Get highest value of a record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have following query which returns samples with all severity level associated with it.

But I need only one severity to pick with highest rank level.

**What I tried**

```
select S.sampleCode,asd.severityLevelRank
from prod.Samples S
left outer join prod.SampleFractions sf on sf.sampleId=S.sampleId
left outer join prod.LabRepetitions lr on 
sf.sampleFractionId=lr.sampleFractionId
left outer join prod.LabRepetitionResults lrr on 
lrr.labRepetitionId=lr.labRepetitionId
left outer join prod.AssessmentDataChecks asd on 
lrr.labRepetitionResultId=asd.labRepetitionResultId

group by S.sampleCode, asd.severityLevelRank

order by S.sampleCode desc, asd.severityLevelRank desc
```

**What I Got**

[image]

but I need a sample with the highest rank that is 3.

Comment: add some sample data & desired result.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the highest severity by rank per each group of samples, then you can try using `DENSE_RANK()`.  Note that using dense rank here is very helpful because it alleviates the need to worry about the duplicate sample/severity records you were removing during the `GROUP BY` aggregation.  If a duplicate severity rank appears for a given sample, the rank will not increment.

```
SELECT
    sampleCode,
    severityLevelRank
FROM
(
    SELECT
        S.sampleCode, asd.severityLevelRank,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY S.sampleCode ORDER BY asd.severityLevelRank) dr
    FROM prod.Samples S
    LEFT JOIN prod.SampleFractions sf
        ON sf.sampleId = S.sampleId
    LEFT JOIN prod.LabRepetitions lr
        ON sf.sampleFractionId = lr.sampleFractionId
    LEFT JOIN prod.LabRepetitionResults lrr
        ON lrr.labRepetitionId = lr.labRepetitionId
    LEFT JOIN prod.AssessmentDataChecks asd
        ON lrr.labRepetitionResultId = asd.labRepetitionResultId
) t
WHERE
    dr = 1
ORDER BY
    sampleCode DESC,
    severityLevelRank DESC
```

Comment: By given query it will give me only one record from the query but i need highest rank for each sample.

Comment: @VishwashRoy I updated my answer, your question was not entirely clear as you phrased it.

Comment: I absolutely don't see the purpose of window function in a so simple case. For me, a simple GROUP BY / MAX would do the job, like I suggested in my answer (and like Zohar Peled did too)

Comment: @AFract What hapens if you want other columns?  Then your approach would fail.

Comment: ...and it's "as I suggested in my answer" not "like I suggested"

Comment: Do you see any "other column" in the question ? As no, I don't see the interest of using a convoluted solution where a simple aggregate will do the job. And thanks for the language course, english is not my mother language, like for a lot of people on SO, so I just can do my best to express my ideas :).

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
select S.sampleCode,asd.severityLevelRank
```

By

```
select S.sampleCode, MAX(asd.severityLevelRank)
```

In SELECT.

You can also add

```
WHERE asd.severityLevelRank IS NOT NULL
```

Under FROM

to ignore sampleCode with null values.

Comment: This approach would fail if the OP wanted the entire max record.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, it's a simple `group by` with `max`:

```
select S.sampleCode, max(asd.severityLevelRank) As severityLevelRank
from prod.Samples S
left outer join prod.SampleFractions sf on sf.sampleId=S.sampleId
left outer join prod.LabRepetitions lr on 
sf.sampleFractionId=lr.sampleFractionId
left outer join prod.LabRepetitionResults lrr on 
lrr.labRepetitionId=lr.labRepetitionId
left outer join prod.AssessmentDataChecks asd on 
lrr.labRepetitionResultId=asd.labRepetitionResultId

group by S.sampleCode

order by S.sampleCode desc
```